# Erro em slide ao inserir código php

Tags: php, html, vídeo

Estou fazendo um slide de vídeos e estava indo tudo bem até eu colocar o código php que trás os vídeos do banco de dados qdo eu insiro pelo admin.

Quando eu troco o código abaixo:

```
<div>
    <div u="player">
       <iframe pHandler="ytiframe" pHideControls="0" width="640" height="381" style="z-index: 0;" url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JZLDb_cPMZY?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&fs=1&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por este outro código:

```
<?php
    $busca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios  ORDER BY nome ASC");
       while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){
          echo "<div>
                   <div u='player'>
                     <iframe pHandler='ytiframe' pHideControls='0' width='640' height='381' style='z-index: 0;' url='".$resultado['video']."'?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&fs=1&wmode=transparent' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>";
            } ?>
```

Ele trás os vídeos do banco de dados mas acontece duas coisas estranhas. A primeira é que o vídeo que vinha com aquele imagem inicial do quando carregada vem preta e a segunda, é que antes, se eu estava vendo um vídeo e clica-se em next ou prev pausava o vídeo, mas agora não está mais pausando, se alguém puder me ajudar o erro está ai nesse bloco de php quando eu troco mas não estou enxergando.

Answer (score 0):

Inverta as aspas duplas pelas simples, veja se funciona.

```
echo '<div>
          <div u="player">
              <iframe pHandler="ytiframe" pHideControls="0" width="640" height="381" style="z-index: 0;" url="'.$resultado['video'].'?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&fs=1&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe
          </div>
      </div>';
```

É uma tentativa...

Comment: Mastria beleza vou tentar

Comment: Mastria não funcionou mas agora a única coisa que acontece é que o vídeo não pausa quando eu clico em next ou prev só para desencargo eu me baseei neste site http://www.jssor.com/demos/video-gallery.html